# How can I view iDeleted Messages sent from my apple id?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

After deleting iMessages that have been sent or received by my Apple ID, can I thereafter retrieve them or view them (perhaps online or on another device)?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what you are asking here. Do you want to see your messages on a computer or an iPhone/iPad or somewhere else? Only messages sent (as in the title) or also the ones you received?

Comment: I'm trying to read any and all iMessages sent or recieved using my apple id. I'd like to view them on my iPhone

Comment: If they have been deleted from phone. Is there a way to still access them if they were using ur apple id?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy to use method to access iMessages once they are deleted. You might be able to fiddle with the backup files in iTunes to recover them but even that only would work until the next time you backup your device.